# Socket in php send receive messages through persistent connection

Tags: php, sockets

I have following scenario:

1. PHP persistent socket server made it run through console in infinite loop

It is my server.php and running it once by using ' php server.php ' command from command line.

```
    <?php
    // set some variables
    $host = "127.0.0.1";
    $port = 3000;
    // don't timeout!
    set_time_limit(0);
    // create socket
    $socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0) or die("Could not create socket\n");
    // bind socket to port
    $result = socket_bind($socket, $host, $port) or die("Could not bind to socket\n");
    while(true) {
        // start listening for connections
        $result = socket_listen($socket, 3) or die("Could not set up socket listener\n");
        // accept incoming connections
        // spawn another socket to handle communication
        $spawn = socket_accept($socket) or die("Could not accept incoming connection\n");
        // read client input
        $input = socket_read($spawn, 1024) or die("Could not read input\n");
        // clean up input string
        $input = trim($input);
        echo "Client Message : ".$input;
        // reverse client input and send back
        $output = strrev($input) . "\n";
        echo socket_send($spawn, $output, strlen ($output), 0) or     die("Could not write output\n");
        // close sockets
     }
     socket_close($spawn);
     socket_close($socket);
    ?>
```

2. Client.php here from this file I am sending message to socket server: At this point I am successful to send message to my socket server.

   ```
   <?php
   $host    = "127.0.0.1";
   $port    = 3000;
   $message = "Abhi ye sab kaise karen ahm asdasdasdasd";
   //echo "Message To server :".$message;
   // create socket
   $socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0) or die("Could not create socket\n");
   // connect to server
   $result = socket_connect($socket, $host, $port) or die("Could not connect to server\n");  
   // get server response
   //Send the message to the server
   if( ! socket_send ( $socket , $message , strlen($message) , 0))
   {
          $errorcode = socket_last_error();
          $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);
          die("Could not send data: [$errorcode] $errormsg \n");
   } else {
          echo "Message send successfully \n".$message;
   }
   //socket_close($socket);
   ?>
   ```
3. Receiver.php another file where I want to receive response my socket server is sending which is not working and Its keep on loading with out giving any out put.

   ```
   <?php
   $host    = "127.0.0.1";
   $port    = 3000;
   $message = "Abhi ye sab kaise karen ahm ";
   //echo "Message To server :".$message;
   // create socket
   $socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0) or die("Could not create socket\n");
   // connect to server
   $result = socket_connect($socket, $host, $port) or die("Could not connect to server\n");  
   // get server response
   //Send the message to the server
   while(true){
       $from = '';
       $port = 3000;
       echo socket_recvfrom($socket, $buf, 12, 0, $from, $port);

       echo "Received $buf from remote address $from and remote port $port" . PHP_EOL;
   }
   //socket_close($socket);
   ?>
   ```

My receiver end is not receiving any out put. I am trying to do this way:

Send message from client to socket server and as soon as socket server dispatch it my receiver end display it, I am successful only up to client where I client.php sending message to server.php but receiver.php is not receiving any thing.

Thanks

Comment: Try receive from the socket that sends in Client.php, that is the socket that the server respond to.

Comment: ' php receiver.php ' command keep on running with out any out put

Comment: That is because you don't have a listener on your `Client.php`

Comment: Is it not possible to receive message in receiver.php or is it bad practice to put receiver code in receiver.php ? My goal is to send data from one end and receive same data at another through same socket server. Sending and receiving in the same file e.g client.php is working @Koebmand STO

Comment: Yes it would be bad practice to send split it up. It is possible, but you need to somehow make server reply to that socket instead, fx by making a port that receive messages and another port that sends messages on the server, but this would be very messy.